# Large file ( 256 MB or more) gets replaced by 128 Bytes / Matlab Workspace Memory Overflow or Limit?

Tags: matlab, memory-management, simulation

I am running a simulation in Matlab 2011b that takes several days. Consequently, I am logging the simulation data in a data structure at every iterations and then to a file ( *.mat format). I am observing a peculiar behavior with my simulation /data logging. I observer that the logged mat file gets replaced by 128 Byte file once it crosses 256 MB or so. I am not exactly sure of the size but I have observed the file size to be near 256 MB or bellow before being replaced by 128 byte file. I am wondering if anyone has similar problem. What is the work around? Is there a Matlab workspace memory limitations of up to 256MB or so? Is there a way to change that limit?

I am using Matlab 2011b release and I run several instances (up to 12 cores in my server) of my script in different Matlab workers using the parallel computing toolbox. They simulations in each workers are independent. Matlab 2011b is running on Linux/CentOS/Mac and the observation is across all the workers and even in Windows 7. Thus I assume it's a setting or configuration of the Matlab that can be tweaked. Any suggestion or work around is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:  I am updating a example script of what my code is doing. The iteration indices may be increase as per the simulation time:

```
%Matlab workspace memory test 
% filename: sim_workspace_mem_test.m
clear; clc;
TotalData=[];
for i=1:1000
   for j=1:1000
    for k=1:100

        data.x=rand(100,100);
        data.y=randi(100,100);

        TotalData{i,j,k}=data;

    end
    filename='SimData';
    save(filename, 'TotalData');
  end
end
```

Comment: There's no such a thing, `.mat` files can be stored in more than 256 MB normally it's only bounded with OS capabilities.
Can you embed the code than produced that issue in your question?

Comment: sounds like you are overriding the file yourself. Is it possible that several workers try to write to the same file? I would suggest writing the data to a different file name each name. Only after verifying the data was written properly would I delete old files.

Answer (score 2):

Try saving it with different names and less frequently, its crazy to save your file a million times.

```
clear; 
TotalData = [];
for i=1:1000
  for j=1:1000
    for k=1:100
        data.x=rand(100,100);
        data.y=randi(100,100);
        TotalData{i,j,k}=data;
    end
  end
    if mod(i,10)==0 %Save every 1 percent progress
       filename=['SimData' num2str(i)]; %Give each savefile a different name
       save([filename, 'TotalData');
    end
end
filename='SimData';
save(filename, 'TotalData'); %Just to be safe, we save the final result
```

Comment: Dannis, saving the file at less frequent rate wont solve the issue I am facing. Do you know if there is a limitation in size of the matlab worker workspace ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this kind of behavior is not caused by a limit on how big files can be (mat files can be a few gb). My guess would be that as the file grows bigger the save gets slower, and therefore some kind of collision/synchronization problem occurs. Thus saving less frequently or with different names should help.

Comment: Dannis: it would cause almost a million files, which I dont prefer. I have to look at the other point you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Note that in the code that I have made, it creates 100 (or actually 101 files). The trick is just to save every 10 iterations of the outer loop, if your process then jams you lose at most 1% progress.